# How to get 3 most frequent column counts separated by year in SQL

Tags: sql, partitioning

I have a database (crimes) and I want to separate per year the top 3 districts with the most frequent amount of crimes in SQL. I have tried the following code but this just
sums the amount of crimes:

```
SELECT 
  year,
  district,
  CrimeID,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY year)
FROM Crimes
```

[image: output wanted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this in Oracle, if that helps (editing to add, it looks like you might be using SQL Server so I have added an alias to the derived table to make it work for that too):

```
SELECT
v.year,
v.district,
v.count

FROM (
    SELECT
    year,
    district,
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rono

    FROM crimes

    GROUP BY year, district
) v

WHERE v.rono <= 3
ORDER BY v.year ASC, v.rono ASC
```